# Complie version higher than Build tool

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, build-tools

Google have recently released API 27. I am planning to update my application with API 27. I have marked that there latest build tool is 26.0.2 and API is 27. If I use like below it can cause any issue in app ?

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and Application's minimum and maximum API is like below

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, make sure you *try* before asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 27
  }
```

Read official guideline about [**`Set Up the Android 8.1 SDK`**](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

Comment: Hello sir ! as per my knowledge 27.0.0 is not released yet !

Comment: oh ! sorry sir ! Thanks for Your nice answer :)

Comment: Looks like you need to check gradle plugin version for this as well. I am getting this error: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.

Answer (score 4):

**1) Build tools version has nothing to do with compile SDK version.**

Your current setup will work fine.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

**2) You should use the newest build tools available.**

If you had an old project you could say this:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
```

**3) Build tools version is picked automatically in Android plugin 3.0.0.**

You don't have to specify it. This is enough:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using last version of android-studio you can remove `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` from your *gradle* it's not mandatory.

The `buildToolsVersion` will work along-side with `compileSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

Your config works. You should use lasted build tool.
From android studio 3.0, buildToolsVersion is ignored. It automatically pick the build tool version for you.